# ¿Cómo obtener un número determinado de decimales usando la función table1?

Tags: r

A partir de una tabla como esta:

```
df <-data.frame(c("72","72","69","70","57","77","74","70","74","78"))
colnames(df) <-c("edad")
df$edad<-as.numeric(df$edad)
```

He calculado el porcentaje de cada grupo

```
    table1::table1(~ .,
           data = df,
           render.categorical="FREQ (PCTnoNA%)",
           render.missing=NULL)
```

obteniendo la media y la mediana (algunas veces con dos decimales y otras veces con un decimal)

```
           Overall              (N=10)
           edad 
             Mean (SD)          71.3 (5.83)
             Median [Min, Max]  72.0 [57.0, 78.0]
```

Me gustaría saber como obtener el resultado con el número de decimales que yo quiero (solo con un decimal) y obtener solo la media en vez de la mediana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table1()` permite definir la función para "dibujar" los valores, en este caso los continuos mediante el parámetro: `render.continuous`, entonces puede reescribir la función por defecto incorporando lo que buscas:

```
# 2 decimales y solo la media
my.render.continuous <- function(x) {
  with(stats.default(x),
       c("", `Mean (SD)` = sprintf("%0.02f (%0.02f)", MEAN, SD))
  )
}


table1::table1(~ .,
               data = df,
               render.continuous=my.render.continuous,
               render.categorical="FREQ (PCTnoNA%)",
               render.missing=NULL)
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, funciona correctamente dicha función